# php insert into returning nothing

Tags: php, html

hello i am trying to program a basic insert into for a project i am doing which will take in the user_id and insert all user information entered into a databse but all that is happening is that i am getting redirected to the php page itself.

im fairly new to this and have researched on the internet to get this far but i am now completely confused. our v=current server does not support PDO(unfortunately) so i am relying on you guys for help.

thanks

here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $server = "server";
    $schema = "schema";
    $uid = "uid";
    $pwd = "pwd";

  $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id']
  $bookName=$_POST['txt_bookName'];
  $bookEmail=$_POST['txt_bookEmail'];
  $address=$_POST['txt_address'];
  $mobile=$_POST['txt_mobile'];
  $telephone=$_POST['txt_telephone'];
  $dob=$_POST['txt_dob'];
  $emergency=$_POST['txt_emergency'];
  $profession=$_POST['txt_profession'];
  $nationality=$_POST['txt_nationality'];

  @ $db = mysql_connect($server, $uid, $pwd);
  if (!$db)
  {
     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
     exit;
  }
  else
  {
  mysql_select_db($schema);

    $query = "INSERT INTO booking
(user_id, bookName, bookEmail, address, nationality, 
mobile, telephone, dob, emergency, proposed_date, 
profession ) 
values ('$user_id', '$bookName','$bookEmail','$address','$nationality', 
'$mobile', '$telephone', '$dob', '$emergency', '$proposed_date', 
'$profession')";

  $result = mysql_query($query);
 if ($result)
    header("Location: payment.html");
   else{
   header("Location: bookTour.php");
   }
  }
   mysql_close();
?>
```

update with form code

it has been edited for easier observation

```
function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
  if (document.getElementById){
    var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
    for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
      if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
        if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
          if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
        } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
          if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
          if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
            min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
            if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
      } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
    } if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
    document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
} }
</script>

</head>
<form id="frm_booking" name="frm_booking" action ="InsertBooking.php" method="post">
<body> 
<div class="cssname">
  <p>Book Tours</p>
</div>

<div>

  <label><strong>Book Tours</strong></label>
<form>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><strong>List of Tour Details</strong></p>

  <table width="666" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
  <label>
        <input name="txt_bookName" type="text" id="txt_bookName" placeholder="Name"/>

        <input name="txt_bookEmail" type="email" id="txt_bookEmail" placeholder="Email@email.com"/>
  <label>
        <input name="txt_address" type="text" id="txt_address" placeholder="Address"/>
      </label></td>
    <input name="txt_nationality" type="text" id="txt_nationality" placeholder="Nationality"/></td>

   <input name="txt_mobile" type="text" id="txt_mobile" placeholder="Mobile"/></td>
 <input name="txt_telephone" type="text" id="txt_telephone" placeholder="Telephone"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     &nbsp;</td>
    <input name="txt_dob" type="text" id="txt_dob" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/></td>
<input name="txt_emergency" type="text" id="txt_emergency" placeholder="Emergency Contact"/></td>
 <select name="lst_tour" onchange="">
        <option value="">Select a Date:</option>
        <?php include 'tourSelect.php' ?>
        <?php 

foreach ( $results as $option ) : ?>
        <option value="<?php

          echo $option->departure_date; ?>"><?php echo $option->departure_date; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
        <strong>Type</strong> <strong>date</strong> <strong>here</strong>:
<label>
          <input type="text" name="txt_projectDate" id="txt_projectDate" placeHolder "Enter date selected at the left"/>
        </label></td>
<input name="txt_profession" type="text" id="txt_profession" placeholder="Profession"/></td>

        <textarea name="txt_statement" id="txt_statement" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Say a short sentance about yourself"></textarea>

        <input name="btn_book" type="submit" class="btn_ragister" id="btn_book" value="Book Now!" style="background-color:#FFF"; border="1" />
```

Comment: try to add `or die(mysql_error())` before the semicolon after the mysql_query. It will tell you if something is wrong.

Comment: You have a massive [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability.

Comment: it is just going to its own php page and doing nothing so even the die(mysql_error()) doesnt get run

Comment: for example the page above is insertours.php when i try to submit the form the address bar just links to this page and does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You really should sanititze your user-input before using it in a query, otherwise your site is vulnarable to SQL-injection.

```
$bookEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txt_bookEmail']);
```

Repeat that for all your vars and possibly it will solve your error also (depends on the input used).

Also: look if mysqli is enabled, it's way better than the mysql-extension (if PDO isn't available).

Comment: do you think this is the answer to OP question?